# Trying to get IF/IS to change SRC if certain Class is present

Tags: jquery

Having to trouble trying to get this function to work.

```
$(".chopping").click(function() {
if($("#sink").is('.1-0sinkblack')) {
$("#accessories2").attr('src', 'chooser/acc/1-0-cb.png');
}

});
```

Have got the below code working without the if/is function, but adding in the if/is doesn't seem to work. Am I missing something? All DIV's are working correctly I believe.

```
$(".chopping").click(function() {
$("#accessories2").attr('src', 'chooser/acc/1-0-cb.png');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".chopping").on('click', function() {
    if($("#sink").hasClass('1-0sinkblack')) {
        $("#accessories2").attr('src', 'chooser/acc/1-0-cb.png');
    }

});
```

Here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/78zx4/

There is no issue with using [**is**](http://api.jquery.com/is/) function, you might need to revise code with [**on**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function.

Comment: Tried this but still no luck.

Comment: try jQuery `on` function with latest version.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$(".chopping").click(function() {
if($("#sink").hasClass('1-0sinkblack')) {
$("#accessories2").attr('src', 'chooser/acc/1-0-cb.png');
}

});
```

or

```
$(".chopping").click(function() {
if($("#sink").attr("class")=='1-0sinkblack') {
$("#accessories2").attr('src', 'chooser/acc/1-0-cb.png');
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Most cleanest solution should be:

```
$(".chopping").click(function() {    
   if($("#sink.1-0sinkblack").length == 1) {
       $("#accessories2").attr('src', 'chooser/acc/1-0-cb.png');      
   };
});
```